# Is there a way to flag (at compile time) "overridden" methods whose signatures don't match base signature?

Tags: c++, virtual, overriding

Basically, I want the C# compiler functionality of its `override` keyword in my C++ code.

```
class Base
{
   virtual int foo(int) const;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
   virtual int foo(int); // wanted to override Base, but forgot to declare it const
};
```

As we all know, the above code will compile fine, but yield some strange runtime behavior.  I would love my C++ compiler to catch my poor implementation with something like C#'s `override` keyword.  Are there any keywords like "override" being introduced into C++, or are we stuck with `#define override virtual` to show our intent? (actually, I do not do this - I hate using the preprocessor to "extend" the language).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't wait for C++0x, Visual C++ already has this override keyword. (Since 2005 I believe). There the syntax is:

```
virtual int foo(int) override;
```

You're not obliged to type it, however. And its a non-standard microsoft extension.

Comment: apologies to Naveen - yours is the correct "future" answer; however, for my current needs (I use VS2005), this works!! I tagged this answer as "answering" my question, but +1 Naveen's answer

Answer (score 3):

As far I know, this is not possible with the current standard. You can do it in the upcoming C++0x. See here for more details: [Explicit virtual function overrides](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Explicit_virtual_function_overrides)

Comment: Each time I discover something about C++0x I find the syntax uglier and uglier... Surely it's just me right?